# Why does this Kotlin code with generics produce a Type Mismatch compiler error?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Misc.kts contains:

```
class E
fun <B> foo(): B {
    return E() // <--- Error here
}
fun bar() {
    val r = foo<E>()
}
```

Error is `Type mismatch: inferred type is Misc.E, but B was expected`.  This compiler behavior surprises me.  I'd be grateful for an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of generic functions as cookie cutters for functions. For any value of `B`, your generic function definition can stamp out a different function cookie.

There is one value of `B` that can make `return E()` legal. That's when `B` is `E`, which is the case in the call too `foo<E>()`. However, this is the *only* such case. What happens if I call `foo<Int>()`? You can't return an `E()` when an `Int` is expected.

For your function definition to be valid, it's insufficient for there to merely exist one return value which is compatible with `B`. Your returned value must be compatible with *all* possible values of `B`.